# Surface area of a convex hull in 3D

Tags: cgal

Trying to calculate the surface area of a convex hull in 3D, using CGAL. I have looked at the user manual (http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_3/index.html#Chapter_3D_Convex_Hulls) and have not found any material covering this. I have tried to use polygon_area_2d to calculate the area of the convex hull facets, but have not been successful. Has anybody successfully calculated the area of a 3D convex hull/any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this [example](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_3/Convex_hull_3_2quickhull_3_8cpp-example.html), you compute a triangulation of the convex hull. Them iterating over all the facets of the polyhedron, you can compute the area of each triangle and get the result.

See also [this function](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/group__squared__area__grp.html)

Comment: Thank you; I had seen your previous answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801637/cgal-how-to-efficiently-calculate-the-area-of-facets-of-a-polyhedron) and applied a portion of the code there to calculate the areas from the example you provided above (is this approach valid?). Another followup question is: where is it specified that the convex hull will only consist of triangulation (and not >3 sided facets)?

Comment: It's not and it should. I'll add it. Thanks.